# Ranking table with sorting & dynamic columns

Tags: angularjs, sorting, filter, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to do a ranking table :

I have an object `scores` with the total of points, and each "challenge" with the points associated to this challenge. My principal problem is to run through `scores` to create a `th` tag for each challenge & to sort these after.

**The aims :**

- The number of challenge must be dynamic
- Sort by total (done) & by challenge

**My problems :**

- How use ng-repeat for the array of challenge
- How to sort these

**My advancement :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.sortType = 'points';
    $scope.sortReverse = false;
  $scope.scores = { 
      "6":{
        "total":5, 
        "challenges":{
          "1":{
        "challengeId":1},
      "2":{
        "point":2,
        "challengeId":2}
      }
    },
    "21":{
    "total":2, 
    "challenges":{
      "1":{
        "point":1,
        "challengeId":1},
      "2":{
        "point":1,
        "challengeId":2}
          }
        },
      }
}

myApp.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
    return function(items, field, reverse) {
      var filtered = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        filtered.push(item);
      });
      filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
      });
      if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
      return filtered;
    };
  });
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>
          <span ng-click="toggleSort($index);sortReverse=false">+</span> 
          Total 
          <span ng-click="toggleSort($index);sortReverse=true">-</span>
        </th>
        <th ng-repeat="challenge in scores.challenges">
          <span ng-click="toggleSort($index);sortReverse=false">X</span> 
          Challenge n° 
          <span ng-click="toggleSort($index);sortReverse=true">Y</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tbody ng-repeat="score in scores | orderObjectBy:sortType:sortReverse">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ score.total }}</td>
          <td ng-repeat="challenge in score.challenges">{{ challenge.point }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/13558/)

**Thank you!**

Comment: The challenges are the same for all scores?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the fiddle. When you want to order by a nested value this is how you specify the orderString (In your case it will be by a particular challenge ID):

```
$scope.orderType = "challenges."+challengeId+'.point';
```

Also I added a filter which convert the object in an array:

```
.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function (items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(items, function(item, key) {
      item.key = key;
      filtered.push(item);
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Then your html should look like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="score in scores| orderObjectBy | orderBy: orderType:sortReverse">
    <tr>
     <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
     <td>{{ score.total }}</td>
     <td ng-repeat="challenge in score.challenges">{{ challenge.point }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Check this working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/13564/

Comment: Okay, in this case it's working, but for real the variable $scope.scores is dynamic (from database) so this line must be dynamic we don't know the index [6] `ng-repeat="(key,challenge) in scores[6].challenges"`

Comment: That is why I ask if the challenges are the same for all scores, even though they change dynamically. You can set the Array Challenges by tacking the first object from your scores Object (Once you get the response from your Server). And the set it with Object.keys(Scores[first_index])